# .each loop is not working in my jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

The code below is written to hide the "IN STOCK" phrase on certain vendors' product pages. I noticed the loop itself isn't running when I used console.log. Could you please help correct the code?

```
function runPmmCustomAllPagesJs($) {
    // This function is called from argento-custom.js once dom is ready and jQuery obect is available.
    // $ has the jQuery object.

    var docloch = document.location.href,
        scree = [screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight],
        thisVal = "",
        tAlign = "left",
        afterwhat = "h3",
        df,
        hide_inStock= [':"JV', ':"KE', ':"MB', ':"WD'],
        doc_text=$(document).text(),
        v_code;
        
        
    // hides the "IN STOCK" phrase on certain vendors' product pages
    $(hide_inStock).each(function(v_code){
        console.log('v_code: ' + v_code);
        if (doc_text.indexOf(v_code)>1){
            $(".stock").hide();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `:"JV` etc doesn't lool like a valid selector - so `$(hide_inStock)` will have no result

Comment: What is ```v_code``` value? seems to be forgotten.

Comment: @Bravo, hide_inStock is an array. I think the loop should run as many time as there are elements in the array. Am I correct?

Comment: oh, right ... sorry, I keep forgetting how jquery works - yet, you say the loop isn't running - of course, `v_code` will be, 0, 1, 2, 3 - because jquery each is nothing like array.forEach

Comment: @Bravo, why is the loop running only once?

Comment: probably because you `return false;`

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. It should at least run twice for indexes 0 and 1.? console.log prints just 0.

Comment: @Bravo, found out why, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `false` is returned from the predicate, the iteration is ended prematurely. Return something else or even nothing if you want it to get to the end.

Also, remember that the first argument passed to `.each` is the index.

```js
$([1, 2, 3]).each((_index, value) => {
    console.log(value);

    if (value === 2) {
        return false;
    }
});
// 1
// 2
```

Comment: Richie Bendall, could you please have a look at the post on trouble reading active elements? Link to it is here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364211/hide-open-active-accordion-when-another-accordion-is-clicked